# Is it good or bad to compete in a higher weight class?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, competition

Is it good for my learning process to compete in higher weight class?

My weight is 63

In many BJJ events you have -64, -70, -76, ...

Normally I should compete in -64 but I prefer competing in -70. Am I doing it right? I would say it's ok, because BJJ teaches you to defend yourself against all types of opponents (including big people).

Comment: Why do you prefer that weight class?

Comment: I was competing in -70 before, and I dropped off weight but never changed the weight class.

Comment: So...have you competed in -64? What was the problem with it?

Comment: No kardeş, I only competed in -70 and never competed in -64. I'm used to -70 that's why I don't want to compete in -64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be fine in the -64 bracket. Give it a try.

If you really miss the heavier folks, compete in open-weight as well.